# How to move large project to webpack

Tags: webpack

We have a large project without any explicit file dependencies specified. I want to move this project to webpack to start using explicit dependencies. But the project is quite big so I won't be able to do that very fast. I think I'd need to do it somehow partially. Are there any approaches to do that?

Comment: What's your stack for your application?

Comment: it's angular plus jointjs and some utility libraries like lodash